# Bootloop behavior for Win10 installation or Win10 install media

Tags: windows-10, bios, motherboard, uefi, secure-boot

I have a Win10 system I've been using without any issues for ~2.5 years. The mobo is ASUS ROG Crosshair VIII Hero Wifi. The CPU is Ryzen 3950x.

Last week I had a weird occurrence where the system would not power up reliably. It kept rebooting at [this screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIqxa.jpg), and every 2-3 reboots it would say "Preparing Automatic Repair", but then still reboot. After hours of this, recovery mode finally launched successfully, and I deleted the last quality update, then went back into many more bootloops until I eventually got into recovery mode again luckily, deleted the last feature update, and then the system booted successfully. I was convinced the issue had something to do with an MS update, but today I am not so sure about that anymore.

Today the same thing happened. I did get recovery mode to start once, and I deleted the last quality update. But after that it was just bootloops forever. So, I did the following:

- Disconnected every single piece of hardware from the mobo except the CPU/RAM/fans/GPU
- Reduced to 1 stick of RAM that I'm 99.9% sure is ok
- Reset BIOS to defaults and (eventually) cleared secure boot keys

Now, two experiments:

1. Try to boot a Win10 USB install drive. The system exhibits the same behavior it did when I was trying to boot my Win10 SSD above. Gets to the screen linked in the image above, then reboots. The Win10 install dialogs never even begin. I tested the USB drive in another machine and it works as expected there.
2. Try to boot a Win7 install CD. It works fine (I did not complete the installation, but the dialogs at least begin as expected).

Unfortunately I do not have a Win7 USB installer nor a Win10 install disc. So I cannot 100% rule out that this weirdness has something to do with USB. But I don't think that is the case (I'm using a USB port directly on the mobo and have tried multiple ports, and the same behavior was happening with the M2 SSD).

So, I think it has something to do with Win10? Secure boot or UEFI maybe? I have tried every possible combination of settings related to those things in BIOS, and never any difference in behavior.

I am more stumped than I've ever been in 2 decades of building systems. Any ideas?

Comment: "Secure boot or UEFI maybe?" - Secure Boot isn't your issue, and if UEFI was your issue, your system wouldn't even attempt to start Windows.  You don't indicate which cumulative update or feature update you ended up NOT installing.

Comment: I have no idea what "last update" I uninstalled. The recovery mode UI doesn't explain that, it just allows you to "uninstall last [quality, feature] update". And I'm not sure my system **is** attempting to start Windows. When I boot from the thumb drive, I only see the ASUS logo and the ASUS spinner. I see nothing to indicate what is happening wrt the Windows installer. Very confusing. I don't think the hypothetical last updates are relevant anyway, considering what is happening with the USB installer.

Comment: "There is a high possibility your storage device is failing." - There is no storage device attached currently. I told about last week's SSD boot woes as background. But my current attempts are a naked system with zero SATA cables connected. I'm only attempting to boot a Windows install media.

Comment: Anyways, I go back to my earlier statement, it's not UEFI or Secure Boot. As for the storage system, while not relevant to your question, I can almost guarantee you that your original issues were due to it failing.

Comment: I'd rethink that guarantee. I've since tried starting the system (still storage-free) with a bootable Ubuntu USB drive, and it behaves exactly the same as it did with the Win10 USB installer. Briefly shows an Ubuntu branded spinner under the ASUS splash screen, then promptly reboots. The only potential culprits are: mobo, CPU, PSU (I'm ruling out GPU and RAM since I have spares of each, and the behavior persists).

Comment: @Ramhound turns out it was the last thing I expected: the CPU. Was able to prove that using another AM4 system I have and swapping CPUs. Never in 25 years of building systems have I had a CPU go bad. But, I guess it makes sense that the bootloader would execute some instruction that BIOS does not require (and the bad transistor is in the physical execution path of that instruction), hence the behavior I was seeing.